# Math.Random the highest value

Tags: javascript, math

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Math.random()</h2>

<p>Every time you click the button, getRndInteger(min, max) returns a random number between 0 (included) and 10 (excluded):</p>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = getRndInteger(0,10)">Click Me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function getRndInteger(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The code above from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_random_function) says that function returns sth between 0 (included) and 10 (excluded). 
As Math.Random gets the value from 0 to 1, I think it can return 10 value, just the possibility is really rare. It could be `1 * (10 - 0) + 0 = 10` and Math.floor will not have anything to do here. Am I not right and 10 value is really excluded?

Comment: `Math.random` returns a value between 0 inclusive and 1 exclusive. `1 * (10 - 0) + 0` is not possible.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I was wrong, thanks.

Comment: @Xufox Would you like to make an answer, in order to get this out of the list of unanswered questions?

Answer (score 0):

> The Math.random() function returns a floating-point, pseudo-random
> number **in the range 0 to less than 1 (inclusive of 0, but not 1)** with approximately uniform distribution over that range — which you
> can then scale to your desired range.

-- [Math.random() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)